# SQL not updating properly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

For our project we have a table where we get all football results for one match day. Depending on their SQL database value, an input gets shown where the user can add the match results. When we hit the 'save' button, the insert into the database gets triggered. For some reason, from time to time not all lines get added to the database.

```
[HttpPost("UpdateMatchDayScore")]
public async void UpdateMatchDayScore([FromBody]UpdateMatchDayScoreViewModel[] model)
{
    var matchDayId = model[0].matchDayId;
    var poolId = model[0].poolId;
    RankingSearch rankingSearch =  await _rankingService.CreateNewRanking(matchDayId, poolId);
    foreach (var t in model)
    {
        _matchDayService.UpdateMatchDayScore(rankingSearch.RankingId,t.poolId, t.homeTeamId, t.awayTeamId, Int32.Parse(t.scoreHome),Int32.Parse(t.scoreAway), t.matchDayId);
    }
    _calculateRanking.CalculatePosition(rankingSearch.RankingId);
}
```

This is our viewmodel:

```
public class UpdateMatchDayScoreViewModel
{
    public int poolId  { get; set; }
    public int homeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int awayTeamId { get; set; }
    public string scoreHome { get; set; }
    public string scoreAway { get; set; }
    public int matchDayId { get; set; }
}
```

This is our matchday repository:

```
public async void UpdateMatchDayScore(int poolId, int homeTeamId, int awayTeamId,
int scoreHome, int scoreAway,
int matchDayId)
{
    using (var conn = _connector.OpenConnection())
    {
         await conn.QueryAsync<MatchDay>(StoredProcs.UpdateMatchScore,
            new
            {
                pouleId = poolId,
                awayTeamId = awayTeamId,
                homeTeamId= homeTeamId,
                scoreAway = scoreAway,
                scoreHome = scoreHome,
                matchDayId = matchDayId
            }, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

This is our matchday service:

```
public void UpdateMatchDayScore(int rankingId, int poolId, int homeTeamId, int awayTeamId, int scoreHome, int scoreAway, int matchDayId)
{
    _calculateRanking.CalculateRankings(rankingId, matchDayId, awayTeamId, homeTeamId, scoreHome, scoreAway);
    _matchDayRepository.UpdateMatchDayScore(poolId, homeTeamId, awayTeamId, scoreHome, scoreAway,
        matchDayId);
}
```

Sample model:

```
    {
                pouleId = 46273,
                awayTeamId = 400069,
                homeTeamId= 400002,
                scoreAway = 2,
                scoreHome = 4,
                matchDayId = 12}
```

We did some math and in total for one matchday(which contains 8 games) opens 41 connections. We think we might be doing to much at once? Could anyone help us out?

Comment: Hi @VincentVH, welcome to SO. It would help if you post code for the `UpdateMatchDayScoreViewModel` class as well a sample data for a test run.

Comment: hi, sorry did not expect such a quick response. I updated it a bit, I might still be missing some stuff.

Comment: No worries. Can you post a sample `model`? (The actual property values)

Comment: I added a sample model, not sure if it will really help that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like an issue with the number of connection, rather it’s the way you are calling your methods.

Your code is mix of Async and Sync methods. On top of it, the Async methods are not invoked properly using “await” at all the places. And this is an open invitation to trouble.

Go through this post to understand the issues you may face when you do that. 
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

> **Note:** This post talks about dead-lock but it is applicable in your case as well.

I am assuming that the `foreach` loop is missing updating some of the records due to not receiving correct `Task` status in some of the cases.

I would suggest that if you are new to `async-await` domain, try your code with only sync methods first and then try to apply the `async` feature.

If some of the methods are `async`-only, you can add `.Wait()` method at the end for your code to wait for the `Task` to get completed before moving to next statement of execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait

Hope this helps!

Comment: We did what you suggested, starting from everything in sync, and slowely adding in our async where required and it fixed our issue! Thanks!